# Why are my rails model validations disabled in unit tests?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation

I have unit tests that check that my model validations prevent invalid objects from being saved.  At some point these stopped working in unit tests for the `Product` model.  It's as if the object is always valid, and so the assertions fail when they test either the result of `valid?` or `invalid?`.  The validations also don't prevent objects that should be invalid from being saved or deleted.

Here's my Product model:

```
class Product < ApplicationRecord
  validates :title, :description, :image_url, presence: true
  validates :price, numericality: {greater_than_or_equal_to: 0.01}
  validates :title, uniqueness: true
  validates :image_url, allow_blank: true, format: {
      with: %r{\.(gif|jpg|png)\Z}i,
      message: 'must be a URL for GIF, JPG or PNG image.'
  }
  validates :title, length: {minimum: 10}

  has_many :line_items
  has_many :orders, through: :line_items
  before_destroy :ensure_not_referenced_by_any_line_item

  private
    def ensure_not_referenced_by_any_line_item
      unless line_items.empty?
        errors.add(:base, 'Line Items present')
        throw :abort
      end
    end
end
```

Here's a test that's failing:

```
  test "product title must be at least ten characters" do   # <-- line 58
    product = Product.new(title: "123456789",
                          description: "yyy",
                          price: 1,
                          image_url: "fred.gif")
    assert product.invalid?   # <-- line 63
    assert_equal ["is too short (minimum is 10 characters)"], product.errors[:title]

    product.title = '1234567890'
    assert product.valid?
  end
```

And here's the result of that test:

```
F

Failure:
ProductTest#test_product_title_must_be_at_least_ten_characters
      [/vagrant/depot5/test/models/product_test.rb:63]:
Expected false to be truthy.


bin/rails test test/models/product_test.rb:58
```

I only had validation tests for the Product model, but I added this for User and it passed, so I think that means whatever the issue is is specific to Product:

```
class UserTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
  test "must have name" do
    user = User.new(name: nil, password: 'secret')
    assert user.invalid?

    user.name = 'bob'
    assert user.valid?
  end
end
```

Versions:

```
ruby 2.3.1p112 (2016-04-26 revision 54768) [x86_64-linux-gnu]
Rails 5.0.0.1
Vagrant: Installed Version: 1.8.6
```

I'm running in vagrant (on MacOS) according to the instructions in Agile Web Development With Rails 5, and this is the project built during the course of that book.  If it helps, my project is at https://github.com/dmoney/depot5 , I'm working on branch `feature`, and the tests pass if I checkout commit `c759738796a0afcf2a7b7853c3f07ba33b9838e0` (which was before all the i18n stuff).

Thanks in advance!

**Edit:** Steps to reproduce in new directory (at least it worked for me):

```
git clone https://github.com/dmoney/depot5.git depot5c
cd depot5c
git checkout feature
bin/rails test
```

Comment: I pulled down your project and wasn't able to see the same errors

Comment: @digicazter Sometimes it only happens after I db:migrate.  Also, it only happens on the 'feature' branch.

Comment: maybe db:migrate was only necessary when going back and forth from the old good commit.  i get the errors when i clone it into a new directory, then switch to 'feature branch'.